# Paypal Payflow Pro : Not signed up for this tender type - 25

Tags: magento-1.9, paypal, paypal-payflow-pro

I am using PayPal Pay-flow pro payment method on my magento store. Now when I enabled it "PayPal express (papal UK express)" is automatically enabled.

Now issue is when I try to place an order this PayPal UK express payment method that time I am getting an error message

```
[response] => Array
 (
    [RESULT] => 25
    [RESPMSG] => Not signed up for this tender type
 )
```

So can anybody please help me why this is happening ?

Please note that I am using sandbox account.

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: No . Can not Find  :(

Comment: I have found one solution. I request to paypal for enabled ACH services in my sendbox account and my issue get resolved for CC payment. I hope it helps you

Comment: Ok thank you jalpesh :) .. I will do same and let you know.